# Is statsmodel/exponential smoothing working correctly?

Tags: python, statsmodels, holtwinters

I am performing a time series analysis using `statsmodels` and the exponential smoothing method. I am trying to reproduce the results from

https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/exponential_smoothing.html

with a particular `dataframe` (with the same format as the example, but only one outcome).
Here are the lines of code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt

fit = ExponentialSmoothing(dataframe, seasonal_periods=4, trend='add', seasonal='mul', initialization_method="estimated").fit()
simulations = fit.simulate(5, repetitions=100, error='mul')
fit.fittedvalues.plot(ax=ax, style='--', color='green')
simulations.plot(ax=ax, style='-', alpha=0.05, color='grey', legend=False)
fit.forecast(8).rename('Holt-Winters (add-mul-seasonal)').plot(ax=ax, style='--', marker='o', color='green', legend=True)
```

However, when I run it, I get the error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initialization_method'
```

but when I check the parameters of `ExponentialSmoothing` in `statsmodel`, `initialization_method` is one of them, so I don't know what happens there.

Moving forward, I removed `initialization_method` from the parameters of `ExponentialSmoothing` within the code, then I get another error the line below

```
AttributeError: 'ExponentialSmoothing' object has no attribute 'simulate'
```

Again, I go and check if `simulate` is not deprecated in the latest version of `statsmodels` and no, it is still an attribute.

I upgraded the `statsmodels`, I upgraded `pip` and I still get the same errors.

What is it going on there?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I am on statsmodels 0.12.0 and it works for me..

Comment: I had the same problem.  I upgraded to 0.12.0 and the problem went away.  However, I have had some instabiity problems with it as the parameters have changed.  Now having problems with TypeError: smoothing_level must be float_like (float or np.inexact) or None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there was a bug in the previous version, that was corrected in the new version of statsmodels. One only needs to update to statsmodels 0.12.0 and this issue is solved.